# Orthonormal basis for L2 (0,1) by using Laplacian's eigenfunctions.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation-theory, laplacian

A standard orthonormal basis for L2 (0,1) is given by the Fourier expansion, as described here, for example ([Orthonormal Basis of $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346191/orthonormal-basis-of-l2?rq=1)). On the other hand, it seems a standard result that the Laplacians eigenfunctions form an orthonormal basis, too.

Since I needed that basis for speeding-up a numerical simulation, I computed them directly:  $\phi_j (x)  = \sqrt{2} \sin( j \pi x )$ for positive natural $j$, eigenvalues $-(\pi j)^2$.

On the other hand, the standard basis previously linked works very well in my script, while $\phi$ causes some troubles. So, before digging into many lines of code, let's start from a simple point. I am honestly not to sure that $\phi$ truly consituted a basis, maybe I just misunderstood this informal claim I remember from some past course. So I ask:

**Does the family $\phi$ constitutes a basis for L2(0,1)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are restricting yourself to functions which vanish at the endpoints: Yes. Indeed, in this case, the Laplacian eigenfunctions coincide with the fourier basis (the cosines are excluded because they do not satisfy the boundary conditions). But the same fact holds in general.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you so much. I forgot these boundary conditions. To drop them I can use the full Fourier basis, which actually **is** the Laplacian eigenfunction expansion. In other words, the two basis I am comparing, standard Fourier and Laplacian, are the same. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @ user233650: Yes