# Proof that $\exp(ikx)$ forms an orthogonal basis of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthonormal

This is likely to be asked in the past, but I cannot find any answers about how to prove $B=\{e^{ikx}:k\in \mathbb Z\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2[-\pi , \pi]$. I find a proof [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-102-introduction-to-functional-analysis-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_102s09_lec14.pdf). This proof is very computational.

Are there any other less computational proofs that doesn't rely on much algebraic calculations? For example, can I prove that the span of $B$ is dense by using the result that if $\langle x,e\rangle=0,\forall e\in B$ then $B$ is an orthonormal basis, or something like that?

Comment: You mean the part where your link says "This, however, is not so trivial" and "the proof is a serious piece of analysis" ?  You are asking if that author was wrong about those remarks?

Comment: Any proof is likely to be computational since you are given a specific collection of functions. For the trig polynomials, it's just easier to show that they are $L^2$ dense. Your idea about the vanishing of the inner product would work nicely for the Haar functions in $L^2([0,1])$ but it is also "computational" and after all, it  is a density argument as well.

Comment: @GEdgar No. A serious piece of analysis does NOT have to be computational. It can be abstract.

Comment: How do you feel about Stone-Weirstrass and density of continuous functions in L^2? These are definitely serious (abstract) facts, but if you accept them, then this falls out easily

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{L}^2([0,1])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346191/orthonormal-basis-for-mathcall20-1)

Comment: The link of cmk is the method suggested by @qbert ... Stone-Weierstrass and density of continuous functions in $L^2$.  Can one prove Stone-Weierstrass (or even Weierstrass itself) without non-trivial computation?  The link in the OP does a proof based on  Fejer convergence of Fourier series.