# Proof that the trigonometric functions form a basis for $L^2[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-series

My math teacher has recently talked about the Fourier series; any periodic function can be written as a sum of trigonometric functions. That's cool and stuff, but he didn't prove it. We only derived a "formula" for the coefficients and without proof, I will feel unsatisfied. I started to dig around the internet and found stuff about Hilbert spaces, Schauder bases and $L^2$ spaces (which is a Hilbert space). I then read that the set $\{\sin(nx), \cos(nx)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis for the space $L^p[0, 2 \pi]$ and, if I have not misunderstood, will prove the thing that I want to prove. I also read about orthonormal spaces and their connection to Hilbert spaces. So in this case I want to see proof that the set of trigonometric functions form an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0, 2\pi]$. The orthogonal part is quite easy and I have searched for proof of the rest for a while and I can't find anything. Maybe some kind person will give me proof of this? However, I don't know how complicated that proof actually is and considering that I have almost no knowledge in this field, a handwavy argument would satisfy me. If not that, then at least guidance. For example, what I need to learn to understand the proof etc.

Comment: Well, one proof uses that these functions are exactly the eigenfuctions of the self-adjoint operator ${d^2 \over dx^2}$, which are known to be orthogonal and compete, but there should exist much more elementary proofs.

Comment: I'm looking at a book called Advanced Calculus by Wilfred Kaplan, 4th edition.The material you want is pages 491-520. It is self-contained: vector calculus does appear in earlier chapters, but this chapter is entirely single-variable. Anyway, you would likely benefit from first learning how to compute examples; a common one is the infinite sum of $\frac{1}{n^2} $  I see, that is exercise 6 on page 503. Seems he does existence first for $C^0$ and piecewise $C^2$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346191/orthonormal-basis-for-mathcall20-1/3293304#3293304

Comment: Do you know some complex analysis?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts No, I sadly don't know anything about complex analysis yet since I am still in high school. Your answer does look interesting though so I might consider learning one or two things about complex analysis!

Comment: You're way ahead studying these things in high school. Complex Analysis is a beautiful area of Math; it's like eating candy, as one Prof I knew put it. You'd enjoy it, and it's a powerful way to address these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the operator
$$
               Lf = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}
$$
on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ of absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^2[0,2\pi]$ for which $f' \in L^2[0,2\pi]$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. This operator is self-adjoint. The operator $R(\lambda)=(\lambda I-L)^{-1}$ exists for all $\lambda\ne 0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$, and is given by
$$
             R(\lambda)f=\frac{e^{i\lambda x}}{1-e^{-2\pi i\lambda}}\int_0^{2\pi}ie^{-i\lambda t}g(t)dt-e^{i\lambda x}\int_0^xie^{-i\lambda t}g(t)dt,\;\;\; \lambda\notin\mathbb{Z}.
$$
The operator $R(\lambda)$ can be found by directly solving the ODE corresponding to $(\lambda I-L)g=f$ for $g$. $R(\lambda)$ has isolated poles at $0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$, and the residue of $R(\lambda)f$ at an integer $n$ is given by
$$
          R_{n}f= \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow n}(\lambda-n)R(\lambda)f=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-int}f(t)dt\cdot e^{inx}=\langle f,e^{inx}\rangle e^{inx}.
$$
This is the one-dimensional projection of $f$ onto the eigenfunction $e^{inx}$. The task of showing $f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\langle f,e^{inx}\rangle e^{inx}$ is reduced to a problem of showing that the sum of the residues of $\lambda\mapsto R(\lambda)f$ in the finite plane is equal to the single "residue" of $R(\lambda)f$ at $\infty$, which is
$$
       \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow i\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-L)^{-1}f=f.
$$
It is a delicate matter to prove such a thing, but it is true in general, and the result can be used to prove the Plancherel theorem for the Fourier transform, as well as the Parseval identity for the Fourier series, and a more general result for self-adjoint operators with mixed discrete and continuous spectrum.